# Will it be possible for the crewed Orion spacecraft to fly over the lunar south pole to land the VIPER rover there?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, orion-spacecraft, artemis-program, nasa-viper

[image: Artemis 2]

[Artemis 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_2), the planned crewed mission of the Orion spacecraft, will be launched in the fourth quarter of 2022 and will then be the first crewed spacecraft to the Moon in 50 years !
[VIPER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIPER_(rover)) is a lunar rover by NASA planned to be delivered to the south pole of the Moon as early as December 2022.
From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VIPER_(rover)#Overview):

> The VIPER rover is part of the Lunar Discovery and Exploration Program managed by the Science Mission Directorate at NASA Headquarters, and it is meant **to support the crewed Artemis program.**

This mission builds on the cancelled NASA rover concept called [Resource Prospector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Prospector_(rover)) which had various launch options, including to fly as a [secondary payload on board the Artemis 2](https://parabolicarc.com/2017/05/01/nasas-resource-prospector-rover-search-lunar-volatiles) in 2022.

So there's a good chance that VIPER will be launched together with the Orion spacecraft.

But will it be possible for the spacecraft to fly over the south pole of the Moon with a flyby ?

(click on the image above for the trajectory)

Comment: Regarding "will be launched in the fourth quarter of 2022" are there any places where I could bet some money against that statement being true?